# Why do higher integer values take longer for the program to run?

Tags: python

I'm using the text file from [this repo](https://github.com/dwyl/english-words/blob/master/words_alpha.txt).

```
f = open("words_alpha.txt")
lists =f.read()
f.close()

# word is the list of random letters
lists = lists.split()


for i in lists[:]:
  if len(i) < 3:
    lists.remove(i)
```

I do not understand why whenever I increase the integer on line 10 (`if len(i) < 3`) the run time increases drastically (when it's 3 it takes 4s to run and when I use 4 it takes 25s, and when running the full program this changes the runtime from being 2s, if it's 2, to over 2 minutes when I use 4 or greater).
Shouldn't larger values in this case not affect anything because the list is the same length? And in the actual program, shouldn't it be faster?

Comment: You're assuming that `lists.remove` is constant time, but that's [also linear](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) - overall what you have is closing in on `O(n^2)` as you increase the value.

Comment: Each `remove` operation has a cost. More of those = slower runtime. If you want consistent performance, use [`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) as this runs *once*.

Comment: Or a _list comprehension_ `[i for i in lists if len(i) < 3]`, which would also be `O(n)` (`filter` gives you an iterator, which may be useful if you don't need to materialise the list at any point).

Answer (score 2):

Because there are more words that have a length less than say 4 then there are words that have a length less than 3. So more removing. And removing from the list is slow.

Try using list comprehension for this:

```
lists = [l for l in lists if len(l) < 3]
```